# rationality of residues of differentials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a smooth curve over a field $k$, $\overline{C}$ the smooth compactification and $S=\overline{C} \setminus C$. We think of $S$ as a reduced divisor defined over $k$. Take the sheaf of logarithmic differentials $\Omega^1(\log S)$ and a non-zero rational section $\eta$. Then there is a notion of residue of $\eta$ at points in $S$.

*Question*: Let $s$ be a point in $S$. Is $\mathrm{Res}_s(\eta)$ an element of $k$ or of the residue field $k(s)$?

Comment: Is $k(s)$ separable over $k$?  If so, then the residue should be an element of $k$.

Comment: Yes, in the case I'm interested in $k$ has characteristic zero. Could you please explain why? Thanks!

Comment: I believe Count Dracula is correct.  I was assuming that the residue would be the trace of the residue obtained from a geometric point after base change.  But that seems to be wrong.

Comment: I think the story is more complicated than it seems at first.  Tate *defines* residues to be elements in $k$, even if the residue field extension is not separable.  Presumably for any other definition of residue, if you apply the trace, you get back to Tate's definition.

Answer (score 2):

The residue of $\text{d}t/(t^2 + 1)$ at the point $(t^2 + 1)$ of $\mathbf{A}^1_\mathbf{Q}$ is the class of $-t/2$ in $\mathbf{Q}[t]/(t^2 + 1)$.

Comment: Could you give more details about how you computed it?

Comment: I used the definition of the residue.

Comment: I agree with your computation.  But I am confused about how this jibes with the Residue Theorem as stated, for instance, on p. 15, Proposition 6 of Serre's "Algebraic Groups and Class Fields".  To extend the Residue Theorem over non-closed fields, presumably at some point we need to take traces.

Comment: Hey ... wait a minute!  According to Tate's "Residues of Differentials on Curves", the residue is always defined to be an element of $k$.  I guess that Tate builds the trace into his definition of the residue.

Comment: Jason, thanks for trying to clarify this! I was also confused about what it is written in Serre's book.

Comment: If you apply the trace to the example given in the answer, you find 0, which is compatible with the residue theorem but not very interesting.